# If Electric potential energy is not zero at infinity, nor at any finite value, when it is?

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-mechanics, electrostatics, potential, potential-energy

The electric force decreases with the distance ($1/r^2$). If that's so, if we don't define zero to be in any finite distance value, nor at the infinity, there's just no zero reference at all for the electric potential energy? Basically what I'm asking is if it's possible to choose an $r_{0}$ such that $\forall r \in \mathbb{R}, V(r)\neq 0 \ \wedge V(\infty) \neq 0$?

Comment: @TejasDahake but imagine we define the potential energy to be some arbitrary constant $C_{1}$ at infinity. Where would the zero point reference be then, if it would exist in the first place?

Comment: Why is it invalid?

Comment: @TejasDahake You can define the potential at infinity to be any value you like, as long as you use that definition consistently. It is the potential difference between points that matters, not its absolute value.

Comment: @TejasDahake: there are lots of theoretical scenarios where the potential is not zero at infinity. Say by example potential of a infinite line charge, sheet, ... .

Comment: @gandalf61 thank you very much for your clarification, I'll look after this issue. But I'm very curious to know what are you actually trying to explain with the statement "as long as you use that definition consistently" ?

Comment: @TejasDahake I mean you should not use one definition of potential at one stage in your calculations and then a different definition at some other stage. You must be consistent.

Answer (score 3):

The absolute value of the electrostatic potential at any point is not important, since we only ever use the *difference* between potentials when solving problems. If you would prefer to set the potential $V(r)$ to be $0$ at some finite radius
$r_0$ rather than at infinity then you simply define it to be

$$\displaystyle V(r) = \frac 1 {r_0} - \frac 1 r$$

in which case $V(r)$ approaches $\frac 1 {r_0}$ as $r$ approaches infinity, and we can informally say that $V(\infty) = \frac 1 {r_0}$.

The potential *difference* between two points with $r=r_1$ and $r=r_2$ is still

$$\displaystyle V(r_2) - V(r_1)= \frac 1 {r_1} - \frac 1 {r_2}$$

and does not depend on your choice of $r_0$.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but in this case, would it exist, this $r_{0}$? (This case where we define the potential energy to be some arbitrary constant C at infinity.)

Comment: Why wouldn't this $r_0$ exist? The key to understanding all this is to understand we *cannot* actually know $V(r)$. Instead we can compute $\Delta V(r)$, which for most of our purposes is enough.

Comment: @arpg You can choose $r_0$ to take whatever value you like. Usually we choose $r_0$ to be at infinity, so $\frac 1 r_0$ is $0$. But if you don't like that choice you can make your own choice - it has no effect on potential *differences*.

Comment: @Gert and @ gandalf61 both of you are not answering directly my question. My question is more related to math, calculus and logic than to physics itself. You can choose any $r_{0}$, right. But imagine the scenario where you choose $r_{0}$ such that $\forall r \in \mathbb{R}, V(r)\neq 0 \ \wedge V(\infty) \neq 0$, is this scenario possible?

Comment: Take $r_0=-1$ for example. This potential is negative for any r. Or, even better, write your potential as $-1-\frac{1}{r}$ so there is no reference to some hypothetic $r_0$. You can add any constant and this constant does not have to be related in any way to some position.

Comment: @nasu hold up, if you take $r_{0} = -1$ that means $V(-1) = 0$, no?

Comment: @arpg It would do, except that we know that $r \ge 0$  everywhere in Euclidean space, so there are no points where $r=-1$.

Comment: Mathemartically yes, but there is no point with r=-1. In sperical coordinates r is always positive. If you want to discuss an arbitary function of r ther isno point to muddle the question by calling it electric potential of a pint charge.

Answer (score 0):

There is no requirement that the force must be zero where the potential energy is zero. The zero point of the potential energy is arbitrary and can be chosen essentially anywhere. We usually choose “infinity” for mathematical convenience, but it is not necessary. If another location is more convenient for a specific problem, then we can choose that location as desired. The value of the force at that location is irrelevant.

Comment: It is not true. There is no need for the potential to be zero at infinity

Comment: I am not getting involved in your discussion.

Comment: @TejasDahake and you are not correct as stated in several other comments there isn't any reason to push the incorrect information here.

Comment: @TejasDahake The first sentence of your third comment to the OP seems to says that taking $V$ at infinity to be non-zero makes the concept of potential invalid.   Do you stand by that statement?

Comment: @TejasDahake That is not true.  It's *perfectly valid*, although not particularly useful, to set the potential at infinity to be non-zero.  I suspect that you understand all this, but are not expressing yourself well.

Comment: @TejasDahake I just read your apology [in the comments to a different post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/691676/5739).  I accept that, but I will leave my comment here so that novices will understand that there is confusion.

Comment: @garyp fine sir, although I've deleted my comments which seems misleading for people.

Comment: @garyp feeling sad for coming with wrong concept for this topic but feeling more happy for going back home with the right concept :) thank you all!